# Custom Login Service or Database Query?

Tags: spring-security

I am just starting to work with Spring Security and I know that there are two methods in which you can access the username and password from the database: Creating a custom login service bean or creating sql or hql queries in the xml configuration. Do both options exist purely for ease of use for multiple parties, or should either method be used in different situations? Just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both are almost same but service gives you more finer control over login process as you can write certain logic with method loadUserByUsername. for example load permission or build different user object which is not mapped with hibernate domain object. 
Personally i prefer service.